# Printing something in a value-returning method

Tags: java, methods

Suppose I have a method:

```
public static int square(int x) {
    System.out.print(5);
    return x*x;
}
```

I call this method in the main method as follows:

```
System.out.print("The square of the number "+7+" is "+square(7));
```

I expect the output to be

```
The square of the number 7 is 549
```

However, the actual output is

```
5The square of the number 7 is 49
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: maybe because `7 * 7` is `49`

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Look at his code again, specifically the location of the `5`

Comment: the expected output would be exactly what it is should be `5The square of the number 7 is 49`

Comment: Apparently you didn't see the System.out.print(5) in my square() method.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Of course that is what is expected, if you know the answer to the question =P.

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted. Isn't this the kind of question we want? The question is clear, the code compiles, and the question gives both the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson What typo? I fail to see it.

Comment: Learn to use a step debugger and you would not have had to ask such a basic question. You would have seen what was happening immediately.

Answer (score 10):

When you call a function, all the arguments get evaluated first before the function is called.

So `"The square of the number "+7+" is "+square(7)` gets evaluated before the `System.out.print` that prints it.

Thus `square(7)` gets called, which then calls `System.out.print(5)` *first* - before the calling `System.out.print`.

After `square(7)` returns 49, the string evaluates to `"The square of the number 7 is 49"`, which then gets printed.

To make it even more explicit it's as if you did this:

```
String toPrint = "The square of the number "+7+" is "+square(7);
System.out.print(toPrint);
```

Comment: I have a question, the stackframe of method `square` is allocated after the stackframe of the method `System.out.print`, or before it?

Comment: @Sean: I *believe* that `square` is called, the stackframe is allocated, the function runs fully, returns the result, stackframe is deallocated, etc., all before the outer call to `System.out.print("The square ...` even begins happening (definitely before its stack frame is allocated).

Comment: ya, that's make sense, all that happened before parameter was coped into the stack of `System.out.print`

Answer (score 4):

The line `System.out.print("The square of the number "+7+" is "+square(7));` compiles to:

```
System.out.print(new StringBuilder()
                 .append("The square of the number ")
                 .append(7)
                 .append(" is ")
                 .append(square(7))
                 .toString());
```

Combined with your method `square()`, the sequence of method calls you would see if you stepped through the code with a debugger is:

```
new StringBuilder()
append("The square of the number ")
append(7)
append(" is ")
square(7)
  print(5)
append(49)                                 <-- value returned by square
toString()
print("The square of the number 7 is 49")  <-- value returned by toString
```

As you can see, it calls `print(5)`, *then* `print("The square of the number 7 is 49")`, resulting in the output:

```
5The square of the number 7 is 49
```

Answer (score -2):

You have two options, either you return the value you want to print from the method, or you just do System.out.print inside the method.

Do you really want to print `5` from `square`?